# How to induce a connection on endomorphism bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry

Assume $\nabla:C^\infty(E) \rightarrow C^\infty(T^*X \otimes E)$ is a covariant derivative  and $u$ is an element in the endomorphism bundle $End E$. I'm confused why is the induced connection of $\nabla$ on $End E$ is $\nabla^{End(E)}u=[\nabla,u]$. Any hints?

Comment: If I use $\tilde{\nabla}$ to express for the induced connection on $\mathrm{End}\,E$, there is a ''fake'' natural way to define it by $(\tilde{\nabla}X)u:=\nabla(Xu)$ where $X$ is a section of endomorphism bundle, $u$ is a section of $E$, however, $\tilde{\nabla}X$ as an endomorphism does not satisfy the $C^\infty-$linearity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an intuitive picture, you can try this way. If $v\in E$, then $u(v)$ is another section of $E$. Now if we compare $u(v)$ at two different points, intuitively (in coordinates):
$$
u_y(v_y) \approx u_x(v_x) + \nabla u_x(v_x)\cdot (y-x)
$$

But:
$$
v_y \approx v_x + \nabla v_x\cdot (y-x)
$$

So:
$$
u_y(v_y) \approx u_x(v_y - \nabla v_x\cdot (y-x)) + \nabla u_x(v_x)\cdot (y-x) 
$$

We can rewrite the last expression as:
$$
u_y(v_y) \approx u_x(v_y) - u_x(\nabla v_x)\cdot (y-x) + \nabla (u_x(v_x))\cdot (y-x) = u_x(v_y) + [\nabla,u_x]\,v_x\cdot (y-x),
$$

which is now *linear* in $v$ (dipends on $v$ just at the point $x$).

So, the "efficient" connection for $u$ alone is $[\nabla,u]$.

Comment: Formally this is just the Leibniz law(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(abstract_algebra))

Comment: Exactly! I usually think of the Leibniz rule as a way of formalizing the notion of "small change". If $xy$ is a varying rectangle, the variation $x\,dy + dx\,y$ is the "thin" sides that are varying.

Comment: @geodude Thank you very much! Now I see it. But how to understand $u_x(v_y)$ in the last formula? It seems a little irrational.

Comment: It is the linear map $u_x$ applied to the vector $u_y$. Yes, they are at different points. That's exactly what a connection does! We are asking how $u$ changes by changing points, but neglecting the intrinsic change of the vector.